# netbeans: Class path in Class.forName

Tags: java, class, netbeans, path

I wrote a chat java application that use sockets. I have three Netbeans project, 1. Client side, 2. Server side and 3.Tester.
[projects Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnI5F.png)

In the Tester I want to start a Thread for Server class.

```
public class Tester {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //for (int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) {
        final Class clazz = Class.forName("ServerSide");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Method main = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
                main.invoke(null, new Object[]{});
            } catch(Exception e) {
         // improper exception handling - just to keep it simple
            }
        }
        }).start();
   // }
}
```

}

but I always obtain ClassNotFoundException. Is the path wrong?
Thanks a lot. Sorry for the stupid question!

Comment: PS: i added ServerSide project in Property -> Libreries -> Compile

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Class.forName` here? Why not just import the class?

Comment: How did you set up the class path for the test project?

Comment: The final idea is to use Tester to run single istance of Server app and many istances of Client app to test the concurrency of client thread. This cose is the first try.

Comment: add package => Class.forName("serverside.ServerSide");

Answer (score 2):

You must include also the package into the required classname parameter:

```
Class.forName("serverside.ServerSide");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it compiles but the Server doesn't start. it's a fxml class (extends Application) so it should load a stage with the UI, but nothing

Comment: It works. I use :Application.launch(serverside.ServerSide.class, args); Thanks again